# How can I watch Amazon Prime videos using Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, firefox, amazon

How can I watch Amazon Prime videos using Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04? Currently Firefox version is 48.0. When I attempt to watch a video, I get the following Digital Rights Error message:

> Your web browser is missing a digital rights component.
>
> In your web browser’s address bar, type about:addons, press Enter, and then on the left, click Plugins. For the Widevine Content Decryption Module, select Always Activate, and then refresh the video’s page and try watching the video.
>
> If the video doesn’t play, go back to Plugins, click the gear icon at the top of the page, and then click Check for Updates. When the plugins have updated, refresh the video’s page, and then try watching the video.

I didn't find `Widevine Content Decryption Module`.

I searched for a solution, but it didn't work...

One solution I found was to `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer` and then do the following:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:flexiondotorg/hal-flash
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libhal1-flash
```

However, it didn't work and I still got the same Digital Rights Error message.

I am able to watch Amazon Prime videos using Google Chrome, but not with Firefox. I want to know if it's possible on Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I was just reading today how NetFlix which now only works in chrome out of the box will be supported in Fire Fox version 49 out of the box. Hopefully '49  version will work for Amazon Prime too. Isn't there a fire fox web site you could check though? I hope someone with experience answers your question here though.

Comment: I just verified that Firefox 48 wouldn't work but Firefox 49 would. I wrote an answer below. See if it works for you.

Comment: @WinEunuuchs2Unix - I found a link [Watch DRM content on Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm) that wasn't too helpful since I'm on FF 48.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, you can watch Amazon Videos on Firefox but you will have to [use Firefox 49](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/08/firefox-49-linux-netflix-google-widevine-cdm) or newer. At the time of writing, the version of Firefox available in the official Ubuntu repositories is currently at 48, so you will have to use [Official PPA for Firefox Beta](https://launchpad.net/~mozillateam/+archive/ubuntu/firefox-next) to upgrade your Firefox to version 49:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/firefox-next
sudo apt update
```

If you already have Firefox 49 or newer from the Ubuntu repositories without using any PPAs, then you don't need to use the PPA mentioned above unless you would like to try the beta version of Firefox.

Once you have Firefox 49 or newer, open Firefox and navigate to the desired Amazon Video. There will be a ribbon that asks if you want to play DRM content. Alternatively, click on the hamburger menu button and go to "Preferences" > "Content" and check the "Play DRM content" box.

Comment: I guess I'll wait until FF 49.

Comment: @kimbaudi Sounds good since it looks like Firefox 49 is supposedly coming this September.

Comment: Doesn't work on FF 53 either

Comment: Worked seamlessly for me on 16.04 + FF 54.0 just now. This is nice, as I typically use chromium + widevine on Arch linux... I'd been googling for how to do that vs. just generally playing Amazon vids. Thanks!

Comment: see answer by @matrixisreal when using FF 55 or above.

Answer (score 18):

This is actually a problem with enabling DRM content(atleast in the case of newer versions)

So if its an old version see the above accepted answer, and if you have a newer version and still things are not working, this answer is for you.

Firefox disables playing DRM content by default
To be able to watch DRM content **enable it by Selecting "Play DRM Content" in Preferences -> Content.**

Check this out for more info : https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm

Note that I tested this on Firefox 53, I am not sure about older versions.

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me.
Also, check that you're on the correct domain. For example don't navigate to amazon.com if you created your account on amazon.co.uk

Comment: Works for FF 55.0.2 (64Bit) on Linux Mint without additional Plugins. Amazon help is outdated.

Comment: This doesn't work on Firefox 60.0.1 on Lubuntu x86. Widevine is enabled and the DRM checkbox is checked. Yet Amazon Prime complains and doesn't run videos in HD.

Answer (score 6):

If it does not work even with **DRM-content enabled** and **Widevine Content Decryption Module Always Activate** (both are the default for FF 57, 58 and maybe more), try to solve it by installing VLC

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Worked for me with FF 57 and FF 58 (Ubuntu 16.04).

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 20.04, FF 96, after I'd ruled out the usual suspects (DRM, Widevine).

Answer (score -2):

It may be an issue of your browser version make sure your browser's updated. You can re-download it from the Firefox browser and try updating the module.

Make sure that your antivirus and firewall are disabled while updating that might just make some problem with the update process.

If you want a detailed description of the steps involved in updating content decryption module for Firefox I have it here in one of my blog posts feel free to [check it out  here](http://edgtech.com/2017/01/12/how-to-fix-the-netflix-error-with-widevine-content-decryption-module/).

Download Firefox once again from the [official page](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and follow the steps you can fix the issue.