# Can't watch Amazon videos on Ubuntu 18.04.5

Tags: 18.04, amazon

I noticed just this week that I can't watch Amazon Prime videos on any of the three browsers I have: Chromium, Brave, or Firefox.  All three have widevine issues.

It occurred to me that I updated from 16 to 18 in the last two months and this seems to be the cause.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Yes, it says the wide one extension is missing but I could not find where or how to install it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you suffer this kind  of problem --> [How can I watch Amazon Prime videos using Firefox on Ubuntu 16.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/818009/how-can-i-watch-amazon-prime-videos-using-firefox-on-ubuntu-16-04)

All you need to do is simple. Install Firefox version 49 or newer.
If this does not help, check this --> https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/enable-drm

It's because of "Widevine" plug-in issue. Just find "Widevine" things and enable it.
Hope this helps u

Comment: I will try that and report back.

Comment: I have version 92 and same issue:

Comment: Thanks.  I have version 92 and it still didn't work.  I went into settings and found that this box was unchecked and enabled it: 

Digital Rights Management (DRM) Content
Play DRM-controlled content
Learn more

Appears to be working now.  Much thanks.